# WP Title only in lowercase letters

Tags: wp-title

how to get `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` only in lowercase letters ?

I tried a lot but cant get it ! Perhaps one of you can tell me how to proceed ?

Comment: Pretty much the same question as the other one. You might want to read [ask] to see how to get a good answer.

Comment: First of all go to `dashboard -> settings -> General`. There change the title in lower case. Then try to change your `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?</title>` with this code `<title><?php if (is_front_page()) { bloginfo('name');echo ' | ';bloginfo('description'); } elseif ( is_category() ) { single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name'); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title(); }
elseif (is_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; single_post_title(); }
else { wp_title('',true); } ?></title>` See if that helps :) And off-course you can change code as per your need.

Comment: Makes no sense...Like I said, it is only necessary in one position. but I have solution now ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string to lowercase php function, that'll help you out.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to do exactly ?

Comment: `strtolower( wp_title() );`

Comment: I tried this yet, but it doesnt give out in lower signs. It keeps on giving out in normal size

Comment: What do you mean by signs? Symbols?

Comment: characters...i want that the word (the title) doesent have high and low characters...Example: Love should be love

Comment: Then use `get_the_title()`

Comment: I tried this too...same problem !

Comment: You can filter the title. Look into filters for the_title

Comment: can you please tell me how ? it should only be in one place, not generally

Comment: Sorry mate,if you've struggled this far, you need to research this yourself to stop asking vague questions - look at `add_filter` and use it on the title with a function :)

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to do that via CSS. Find out what css classes are referring to post title and add this css rule in your stylesheet (edit to correct the h tag and class to match yours or add a custom class in the  tag wrapped around the wp_title just for this purpose):

```
h3.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense in CSS, because i need it for a link !

Comment: Why it makes no sense? Maybe a little much context will help answer you with better solutions

Comment: css can not be applied to window titles

Comment: @MarkKaplun He did not explain _where_ he wants to use that.

Comment: `wp_title` is used only for the window title, or at least should be used only for that

Comment: For all that are interested in it. It goes like this (trying goes over study :) ):<?php echo strtolower(wp_title( '', '' ));?>